# Calling a function in a third object based on the combination of subclasses as parameters

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

I'm planning to represent a list of nodes.
My base object `Node` can be extended in order to represent different future representations and rules.
For instance, `Node1` and `Node2` are my derived objects.

```
class Node {};

class Node1 : public Node {};

class Node2 : public Node {};
```

For customization purposes, I'm letting a third object called `Rule` have the overloaded function `calc` for specific extensions of `Node`

This is how I imagine the `Rule` object to look like:

```
class Rule : public <some not yet defined pure virtual> {
public:
  static void calc(Node n1, Node n2){
    cout << "Node : Node" << endl;
  }
  static void calc(Node1 n1, Node n2){
    cout << "Node1 : Node" << endl;
  }
  static void calc(Node n1, Node1 n2){
    cout << "Node : Node1" << endl;
  }
  static void calc(Node2 n1, Node n2){
    cout << "Node2 : Node" << endl;
  }
  static void calc(Node n1, Node2 n2){
    cout << "Node : Node2" << endl;
  }
  static void calc(Node1 n1, Node2 n2){
    cout << "Node1 : Node2" << endl;
  }
  static void calc(Node2 n1, Node1 n2){
    cout << "Node2 : Node1" << endl;
  }
}
```

It is intended that the base object of `Rule` can be a pure virtual and must be extended or its extensions can be extended multiple times in order to include function overloads for the newly defined extensions of `Node`

**How can I call the correct function by passing the objects contained in a array/vector/list of the base object?**

```
Node n[2];
n[0] = Node2();
n[1] = Node1();

Rule().calc(n[0], n[1]);
```

> Desired output: Node2 : Node1

> Actual Output: Node : Node
> (obviously, I'm unable to cast objects in such state)

Perhaps I should mention that in my particular case, one single defined `Rule` object is likely going to be passed between `Node` objects and end up in recursive calls as I'm attempting to some sort of propagation

- How can I achieve this?
- Why this design doesn't/can't work?

  - Can it be fixed?
- Does this require a complete code structure rethink?

  - If yes, please introduce me to the correct way

Comment: Could you please give a little bit more of context? In my point of view does not make sense what you are trying to achieve. I would appreciate some context on what you want to achieve, and maybe give the Node properties as well.

Comment: @EsdrasXavier Context: My final objective is to calculate some sort of "infection chance". The node list will represent a graph, in which one or more nodes will be marked as infected. From these nodes, I want to propagate one object Rule through each node's links, where I wish to call Rule().calc(Node, Node). Having extendibility in mind, the Rule object can be extended and have its own calculation methods defined inside. Similarly, the Node object should be extended and could contain more data. (e.g. Node as Person, Node as a Building, Node as public transport, etc)

Comment: @LollosSi I see. Honestly what I would do (based on what I understood), is declare a Interface `Rule`, and each case would have it's own rule. Let's say you want to check for Person and Building, I would create a `PersonRule : Rule`, and the method `calc` would receive `calc(PersonNode node1, BuildingNode node2)`, but each rule would only receive 2 types of Nodes. But as I understand, each rule can be applied for more than 2 types of Node, for example 1 rule could use Person, Building and Transport to execute the calc. Is my reasoning rigth? Just trying to understand the whole picture.

Comment: If I were to do this, a future developer would be required to make more than one new object `Rule` for each new `Node` implemented.
You saw it correct, I'd like to have more than one overload for the function `calc` (where, in my Rule I should have `calc(person, person)` but also `calc(person, transport)` and `calc(building, person)` + other combinations, if one combination doesn't exist, then it falls back to the basic `calc(node, node)` )

Let's say a new node is added, `Airplane`.
Then I would extend the previously defined `Rule` and add my `calc(airplane, etc)` of interest

Comment: Got it, so as I understand you will have and vector of _Node_, and as far as I now, when you initialize a child class and "cast" to a parent class, e.g. `Node* node1 = new Node1();`, it will be known as _Node_ and node _Node1_, what you could do is have 1 method and than check the type and call the rigth function, honestly I think it's a bad idea. What I would do is implement this rule maybe inside the Node class, and have something like `class Person : public PersonRules`, and inside PersonRules I would halde it. This is more an architectural problem than a code problem actually.

Comment: I got it, will rethink the whole structure, thank you!